# Subversion Error E120105 "improper HTTP response"

Tags: svn

This issue is similar to [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538591/error-the-server-sent-an-improper-http-response-on-commit-with-subversion-1-8)

When I try to commit/mkdir to the repository, the svn fails with:

```
svn: E120105: Error running context: The server sent an improper HTTP response
```

Subversion Client Details **v1.8.10**:

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
   compiled Aug  9 2015, 13:48:39 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2014 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.8
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
```

This is the server details **v1.6.17**

```
$ svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)
   compiled Aug 13 2014, 20:41:52

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository back-end (FS) modules are available:

* fs_base : Module for working with a Berkeley DB repository.
* fs_fs : Module for working with a plain file (FSFS) repository.
```

I have tried the solution in the prev question, `~/.subversion/servers` file contains the line

```
http-bulk-updates = yes
```

But it has no effect.

On the other hand, the server is able to accept commits from `svn v1.6 + ra_neon`

Any idea, how to correct?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and also wasn't able to solve it using http-bulk-updates. In my case it seems to be caused by my company's proxy. Basically my idea is: If a proxy / anti-virus / etc disturbs the HTTP communication between SVN client and server, let's simply hide it by using SSL. This solved the problem for me.

If you're using apache2 and mod_dav_svn I recommend this article:
https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/svn-server-on-ubuntu-with-https-access/

Notice that if your repository location is svn://... or http://... you probably have to relocate to https://... afterwards.

Comment: I will try to upgrade to ssl hosting on the server, and then see if the solution works. Thanks, for posing.