# SVN, new file commit failed using VPN

Tags: windows, svn, vpn

My company just installed a VPN. It works, we can access our intranet SVN server but it is impossible to commit a new file. Here is the error :

```
> svn commit -m "Sandbox test" .
Adding         test.txt
Transmitting file data .svn: E120105: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E120105: Error running context: The server sent an improper HTTP response
```

It occurs only when we commit a new file.
These following operations works well:

- update
- modify a file and commit
- delete a file and commit
- delete a directory and commit
- add a directory and commit
- show log
- show repo-browser

We tested on several computer or user, connecting from home or from mobile network. Results are the same.
And all works fine without VPN (from company intranet).

We use TortoiseSVN v1.12.2 (i.e. Subversion v1.12.2) on Windows 10 and I just updated to TortoiseSVN v1.14.0 to test (no difference).

On the server side, SVN version is 1.8.19.

I read some post from [people who had this kind of problem with SVN client v1.8 and resolve it with SVN client v1.9](https://github.com/naver/ngrinder/issues/102). Is it possible that the SVN server v1.8 has the same problem and we should upgrade it ?

Comment: We checked that the firewall on the server side doesn't block messages.
And I also tried to commit with my antivirus switched off, without success.

Comment: I also tried the method explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538591/error-the-server-sent-an-improper-http-response-on-commit-with-subversion-1-8
"ON THE CLIENT MACHINE! Open %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers in a text editor and add the line http-bulk-updates = yes, save the file and see if it helps."
without success. :'(

Comment: If you have server side access can you provide the information from the following command `svnadmin info <server_repo_path>`?

Comment: I'll ask the admin to do it.

Comment: The admin just try but we don't have info command.
Available svnadmin subcommands :
crashtest
create
deltify
dump
freeze
help
hotcopy
list-dblogs
list-unused-dblogs
load
lock
lslocks
lstxns
pack
recover
rmlocks
rmtxns
setlog
setrevprop
setuuid
unlock
upgrade
verify